# ¿Cómo pasar arreglos de numpy como parametros a una función para minimizar?

Tags: python, funciones, optimización, parametros

quiero minimizar la siguiente función

```
def shift(X,dx):
   X = np.roll(X,dx,axis=1)
   return X

def fun(x, il, ir);
   print(il)
   print(ir)
   diff = np.abs(il - shift(ir, int(x))
   return np.sum(diff)
```

La llamada sería

```
il = img1[0:100, 0:100]
ir = img2[0:100, 0:100]
d = optimize.minimize(fun, 0, args(il,ir), method='BFGS', tol=1e-7)
```

Pero los prints en el interior de fun muestran array vacíos
In: []

¿cómo puedo pasar los arrays de numpy a esa función como parámetros adicionales?
La variable dependiente x es unidimensional. Es el desplazamiento en píxeles de una imagen (il) respecto de la otra (ir)

Gracias

Answer (score 0):

Has probado a pasar la tupla de argumentos pero con el igual posterior a la palabra reservada *args*?

```
d = optimize.minimize(fun, 0, args=(il,ir), method='BFGS', tol=1e-7)
```